# How do I re-enable Location permission for an app where user chooses never?

Tags: android, permissions, android-5.0-lollipop, google-places-api

This is very similar to [Enable location services for Android if user chose Never option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31524931/enable-location-services-for-android-if-user-chose-never-option) but slightly different.

I used PlacePicker and during testing when the app asked me to turn on Location, I said "Never"

Now, it looks like i'm stuck with it :( -- reinstalling the app also doesn't help. Surely, there must be some way for user to reset this?

At-least from my testing perspective, this is insanse if it cannot be reset without a factory reset! Using Android Lollipop - any help in getting this done without rooting the device is much appreicated

edit:

1) Tried clearing data from application cache, uninstall, reboot and reinstall - no dice Settings --> Apps -> My App -> Clear Data (and Clear Cache)

2) Tried resetting "All Apps" preferences - i.e Settings -> Apps -> REset app preferences -- still no use

Comment: try deleting the shared preferences for your application: settings > apps > your_application > memory > delete data

Comment: @MojioMS - updated question with things I've tried which includes this

Comment: Using Android Marshmallow? permissions are handled somewhere else here: settings > apps > app configurations (gear-wheel top right) > app-permissions > location > hope you find your application here and can switch the ticker easily.

Comment: i just noticed android-5.0-lollipop tag, sorry. unfortunatly, Android does not support for controling app permission in 5.0 version. Maybe setting back the phone's factory default configuration will work tho.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After many hours of research I finally figured out how to reset this...

I cleared the data for the following Apps - Google Maps, Google Play Services and Location Services and that fixed the problem...Now my app again asks to use Location if it's turned off.

I didn't have time to investigate which of these is the actual service that stores this information. Hope somebody finds this useful

edit: I"m guessing this needs to be done in conjunction with clearing app data and uninstalling and reinstalling it too...unclear if just clearing data from the apps will solve the problem

Comment: you have no idea how many hours this has just taken from my life... it would be nice if the google developer pages for permissions gave some indication as too which google app stored the permission for PlacePicker

Comment: I reset Play Services and Play Store, and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the original posters answer, you can also do this through settings > accounts > google > locations. A pop-up dialog will then ask you if you ant to re-instate the permission. Saves having to clear all the data from your goole apps and re-install.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is very easy and very easy to miss ...

Swipe down from top screen edge to get pull down menu.  Press on "App permission management".  Press Apps and the app you wish to alter Permissions for.  Voila!